# Are time zones lost when passing them via DateTimeFormatter to DateTimeFormatterBuilder?

Tags: jodatime

I need to parse a date using a couple of date formats assuming a particular time zone and then output it in another time zone (i.e. UTC). I was hoping the DateTimeFormatterBuilder could help but it appears the time zone information attached to the parsers and printers is lost/ignored?

See test and output:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParser;
import org.junit.Test;

public class JodaBuilderTest {


@Test
public void aTestOfTimeZoneRetentionOfFormattersPassedToBuilder() throws    Exception {     

    String [] parsePatterns = new String [] { "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "MM/dd/yyyy" };
     String printPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ";
     String inputString = "08/03/2015 01:01:01";

    DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(-3);
    DateTimeParser[] parsers = new DateTimeParser[parsePatterns.length];
    for (int index = 0; index < parsePatterns.length; index++) {

        parsers[index] = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(parsePatterns[index]).withZone(tz).getParser();
    }
    DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
      .append(DateTimeFormat.forPattern(printPattern).withZoneUTC().getPrinter(), parsers);
    DateTimeFormatter parser = builder.toFormatter();

    DateTimeZone parserdtz = parser.getZone();
    System.out.println("parserdtz: " + parserdtz);
    DateTime dt = parser.parseDateTime(inputString);
    System.out.println("parser zone is " + dt.getZone());
    String dtout = dt.toString();
    System.out.println("expecting UTC-3: 2015-08-03T01:01:01.000-03:00");
    System.out.println("got:\t\t" + dtout);
    String dtoutFmt = dt.toString(parser);
    System.out.println("expecting UTC: 2015-08-03T04:01:01.000-00:00");
    System.out.println("got:\t\t" + dtoutFmt);
    org.junit.Assert.assertEquals("2015-08-03T04:01:01.000-00:00", dtoutFmt);

}
}
```

Output is as follows

```
parserdtz: null
parser zone is America/New_York
expecting UTC-3: 2015-08-03T01:01:01.000-03:00
got:        2015-08-03T01:01:01.000-04:00
expecting UTC: 2015-08-03T04:01:01.000-00:00
got:        2015-08-03T01:01:01.000-04:00
```

So it seems to be ignoring the UTC-3 set on the parsers and the UTC set on the printer and defaulting to the system zone (EDT).
Am I missing something or is this expected behavior? Is my only recourse to not use the builder? I also cannot set the zone on `parser` i.e.
    `DateTimeFormatter parser = builder.toFormatter().withZone(DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(-3));`
because that would override the printer. I suppose I could create a separate formatter for the printer, but then what's the purpose of the printer parameter to the builder? Should I set that to null? Doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some clarifications:

**[`DateTimeParser`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeParser.html)** and **[`DateTimePrinter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimePrinter.html)** instances parse/print the `DateTime` according to a certain formatting pattern. However, the time zone and the locale are not a part of the printer/parser instance. They are provided during runtime, on a case-by-case basis. See the signature of [`DateTimePrinter.printTo`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimePrinter.html#printTo-java.lang.StringBuffer-long-org.joda.time.Chronology-int-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-java.util.Locale-):

```
void printTo(StringBuffer buf,
             long instant,
             Chronology chrono,
             int displayOffset,
             DateTimeZone displayZone, // zone provided at runtime
             Locale locale)
```

As for printer - it can read any time zone, so it's not relevant to configure it with one.

Have in mind the fragment from the `DateTimePrinter/Parser` javadocs:

> Internal interface for creating/parsing textual representations of datetimes.

So, the printer/parser itself do not have a timezone set internally. You can remove the `withZone(tz)`/`withZoneUTC()` configuration on the printers/parsers because they don't change anything there anyway.

However, the [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) has. This is the top-level API you should be working with when it comes to the time zones. If you set the time zone `X` on the formatter it will be able to read any time zone string, but the created `DateTime` instances will be converted to that time zone `X`. Likewise, when printing any `DateTime` instance (in any time zone), it will be printed as converted to time zone `X`. If you are indeed trying to parse the string specifically into `-03:00` time zone, you need one instance of a `DateTimeFormatter` and when you want to print it in UTC, you need a different formatter instance.

So, having your original `formatter` (renamed from your `parser`), you can do

```
DateTime dt = formatter.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("-03:00")).parseDateTime(inputString);
```

and for printing:

```
String dtoutFmt = dt.toString(formatter.withZoneUTC());
```

I'm sure it would be a bit more clear if you were using relevant names for your variables - use `formatter` for the `DateTimeFormatter` instance to avoid confusion with the actual `DateTimeParser`s.